# i need to get the system time & store it as a child value in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to add current system time into child data field.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  What language are you using?

Comment: can you tell me with more explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using TypeScript, but this might still give you and idea how you could do it.

My code uses the `event.timestamp` property to get date and time:

```ts
export const onWrite = functions.database.ref('/{databaseName}/{tableName}/{key}').onCreate((event) => {

  let ref = event.data.ref;
  let isCreate = event.eventType == 'providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.create';

  ref.once('value').then(e => {
    // Cloud functions are sometimes executed with a delay and the record might not exist anymore.
    if (e.val() === null) {
      return;
    }
    if (isCreate) {
      return ref.update({
        'createdDateTime': event.timestamp
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The created events for clients won't include this added data yet, only a later change event does.
I'm haven't investigated yet if this can be fixed (perhaps by making use of transaction).

Comment: i need it in javascript

Comment: JS will be pretty much the same. Just a bit different syntax (`var` instead of `let`, `function ()` instead of `() =>`, perhaps others) I'm not used to write JS.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your image description and understood u want to add system time into firebase.
If you want to do you can do that by , like below

```
var fb_db=firebase.database().ref('treeName');
var key=fb_db.push().key;
var updatenode={}
updatenode[key+"\"]= new Date();
fb_db.update(updatenode).then(function(){
    alert("Success")
})
```